# Windows 8 Metro JS, detect closing of application

Tags: javascript, windows, detect

In a Windows 8 Metro application, how do you detect when the user quits the application, or it is terminated by the system?
I need to clear out some data prior to the app closing, like resetting the live tile, and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what you mean by 'when the user quits the application'. You can actually quit/close/terminate an application in Windows 8/RT using Alt-F4 or swiping from the top of the screen to the bottom. Anything else (switching to another app, hitting the Windows key, etc) is just suspending the application.

The short answer is that you can't detect when the app is closed though, only suspended.

When an app is closed it is first suspended. Microsoft recommends that you treat suspension as though the app will be closed because the OS may decide to terminate the suspended app with no warning if there is resource contention.

Here is the documentation on the 'checkpoint' event that is fired when an app is suspended: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229839.aspx

This page walks through how to handle suspending an app: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465138.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I think this post will help you to understand the lifecycle of windows store apps http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464925.aspx

p.s. there is no more "Metro" : )

Comment: I know Microsoft has said their is no "metro" anymore, but until they come up with _one_ good name for what used to be "metro" then there will always be metro still.